# Get values from two different sheets then copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, one for accounts, the other for users. What I want to do is for every user, match the country column on each sheet, then on another sheet add the email address and each different account on separate rows.

My accounts sheet has about 20k rows and users sheet has about  50 rows.

```
Accounts                                   Users
Account         Country                    Email                  Country
1234567         US                         john.doe@compnay.com   US
2345678         GB                         jane.doe@company.com   GB
9876543         GB
8765432         FR
```

This is not looping each row of accounts, it's only getting the first record from each sheet where it matches.

```
Dim accounts As Worksheet
Dim accountteams As Worksheet
Dim usr As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim j As Integer

Set accounts = Worksheets("Accounts")
Set accountteams = Worksheets("AccountTeams")
Set usr = Worksheets("Users")

lastRow = usr.Cells(usr.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If accounts.Range("C" & i).Value = "AU" Then
        accountteams.Cells(i + 0, 1) = usr.Cells(i, 4).Value
        accountteams.Cells(i + 0, 2).Value = accounts.Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What's the value of lastRow, is it as expected?

Comment: lastRow does get me all the values of the users, but it is not looping through every account and adding it where the value = "AU"

Comment: It's probably not doing what you expect because your `i` value is based on rows in the `usr` sheet, but you are using it as the row index for the `usr` sheet, the `accountteams` sheet, AND the `accounts` sheet.